# Nexus Artefact Upload Failure

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

using maven deploy command, I tried to upload artefacts of size (440 MB) in Nexus repository(Nexus Version : nexus-professional-2.13.0-01). Maven version is 3.5.2. Configured my proxy server details in settings.xml

```
mvn -e -X deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=de.test.oca -DartifactId=wildfly-image  -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=tar.gz -Dfile=oca-wildfly-image-0.0.1-snapshot.tar.gz -DrepositoryId=oca-snapshots -Durl=http://xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oca-snapshots
```

Error Message :

```
Uploaded to oca-snapshots: http://xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oca-snapshots/de/test/oca/wildfly-image/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/wildfly-image-0.0.1-20180117.094348-1.pom (446 B at 1.2 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 07:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-17T10:50:54+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact de.test.oca:wildfly-image:tar.gz:0.0.1-20180117.094348-1 from/to oca-snapshots (http://xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oca-snapshots): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact de.test.oca:wildfly-image:tar.gz:0.0.1-20180117.094348-1 from/to oca-snapshots (http://xx.xx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/oca-snapshots): Connection reset
```

In Nexus GUI, I can able to find the tar.gz file uploaded. When I checked nexus.log, I found error message as

```
jvm 1    | 2018-01-17 14:27:17,706+0100 INFO  [qtp1148931253-265705] admin com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.outreach.SonatypeOutreach - Could not download page bundle
jvm 1    | org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
jvm 1    | 2018-01-17 14:27:47,710+0100 INFO  [qtp1148931253-265708] admin com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.outreach.internal.outreach.SonatypeOutreach - Could not download page bundle
jvm 1    | org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
```

I tried to Upload another file with file sizw of 300MB, it works fine.

Is there any file size limit in the Nexus.

Answer (score 2):

There is no filesize limit in Nexus itself. However there might be timeout issues, performance issues with the app or other issues with the underlying OS and filesystem.